# Android dynamic arrangement layout

Tags: android

I'm developing a harmonica playing android app, in which a harmonica instrument is displayed and some part of it are clickable.

I want to show a full width picture of instrument (the height is adjusted accordingly) which some parts of it are clickable and they must be located dynamically according to the picture size.

The problem is I don't know how to use layout elements to achieve this so it's renderable on device with different screen size. What layout to use?

Show the instrument as an ImageView or background of a layout and how to make it fit?

Is there anyway to put the button relative to the width and height of the picture? or it must be done programmatically? and also they width and height must change as holes get bigger or smaller.

I don't have much experience with android layouts and I am totally stuck on how to do this.

This is a sample picture of instrument:

[image]

I want make holes clickable although the picture size change in different devices.

Any suggestion would help me so much.

Answer (score 2):

The `ImageView` has an internal `Matrix` that controls how the image is scaled.

We can get this Matrix and invert it so we can transform touches on the scaled image into coordinates in the original image.

```
float[] xy = new float[]{x, y}; // the xy from the touch event
Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
imageView.getImageMatrix().inverse(inverse);
inverse.mapPoints(xy); // xy now contains the coordinates of the click in the original image
```

Now all you need to do is match `xy` with some saved values for the location of each note.

Comment: Would you please explain more, I didn't get anything :)

Comment: i guess he is trying to pan the image with this piece of code make ontouch event and get x and y from it

Comment: I tried this, when I rotate the phone and touch the same place on the image, it gives different coordinates.

Comment: It seems it only works for images that are transformed using the matrix itself, not those transformed by the system.